# jQuery autocomplete not displaying data

Tags: jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

I am trying to use autocomplete on user name in my asp.net application. I am retrieving the name & associated id from database. I have checked that it is working to the point where my backend code returns the data to frontend. But it is not being displayed in the autocomplete field. Here is my script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            autocomplete();
        });
        function autocomplete() {
            $("[id$=txt_name]").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<%=ResolveUrl("../Services/AutoComplete.asmx/getCustomerDetails") %>',
                        data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.split('-')[0],
                                    val: item.split('-')[1]
                                }
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function (e, i) {
                    $("[id$=hfCustId]").val(i.item.val);
                    $("[id$=txt_name]").change();

                    return false;
                },
                minLength: 1
            });
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: Share your service code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be like this

```
response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                    return {
                                        label: item.split('-')[0],
                                        value: item.split('-')[1]
                                    }
                                }))

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            autocomplete();
        });
        function autocomplete() {
            $("[id$=txt_name]").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<%=ResolveUrl("../Services/AutoComplete.asmx/getCustomerDetails") %>',
                        data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.split('-')[0],
                                    value: item.split('-')[1]
                                }
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function (e, i) {
                    $("[id$=hfCustId]").val(i.item.val);
                    $("[id$=txt_name]").change();

                    return false;
                },
                minLength: 1
            });
        };
    </script>
```